# Move the metaboxes to the very top of post editor

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I have this function that creates a custom metabox (with the metabox .io plugin), i would like the metabox to stay on top just below the title field

this is the code i am using

```
function generator_api() {
    add_meta_box( 
    'generator_api', esc_html__( 'Generator', 'moviewp' ),
    'generator_api_form',
    'post',
    'advanced',
    'high' );
}
function generator_api_form() {
?>
<div class="rwmb-meta-box">
    <div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper">
        <div id="Generator" class="postbox rwmb-default">
            <input type="text" id="term" class="textInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
            <div id="major-publishing-actions" style="overflow:hidden">
                <div id="publishing-action" class="fetch-details">
                    <span class="culo">
                        <span id="hideme">
                            <input type="radio" name="test" value="movie" required="" checked="">
                            <span id="film"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Movie', 'moviewp' ) ?></span>
                            <input id="TV" type="radio" name="test" value="tv">
                            <span id="TV"><?php echo esc_html__( 'TV', 'moviewp' ) ?></span>
                            <span id="movieform">
                                <input title="fetchm" class="rwmb-text" placeholder="IMDb ID" type="text" id="fetchm" name="fetchm" value="">
                                <input type="button" class="button button-primary" id="fetchmovie" name="fetchmovie" value="Movie">
                            </span>
                            <span id="tvform" class="hide">
                                <input title="fetcht" class="rwmb-text" placeholder="TMDB ID" type="text" id="fetcht" name="fetcht" value="">
                                <input type="button" id="fetchtv" class="button button-primary" name="fetchtv" value="TV">
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="publishme"></span>
                    <span id="api_status">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle rotondo"></i><?php echo esc_html__( 'API is online', 'moviewp' ) ?>
                    </span>
                    <div id="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="pagination"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'generator_api' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :)

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function() {
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
    do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'advanced', $post);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes[get_post_type($post)]['advanced']);
});
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'generator_api');
```